# Mathematical proof - problematic issue of random (pseudo-random) numbers

Tags: random-variables, random

I have a problem. I constructed a mathematical proof, but it is based on statistics. I accept that the numbers generated by a particular type of random number generator is random.

Is this assumption is completely incorrect mathematically?
My guess is that from the point of view of technology may have made sense but from the point of view of pure mathematics is not acceptable?

Sorry for the very general question.

Comment: Well, if your argument is based on sampling then it certainly isn't a proof.  Even if the random number generator you used was perfect, you could only hope for a statistical proof (that is, a proof up to some confidence level).  And then, yes...to the extent your generator may be imperfect that would call even that level of proof into quesiton.

Comment: In the proof of it is based on the fact that the infinite number of times a particular event with non-zero probability must exist. I will describe a very simple proof: We have three sets A, B, C. We complement these collections a certain amount of numbers (random). If no number of A + any number of set B not give any numbers from the set C which means that no general solutions. If we can (solution found) repeat this calculation again for the newly generated sets. And so on to infinity. Just that once we not find a solution. The problem is a method of generating sets.

Comment: Not following, sorry.  I suggest editing your post..write out the theorem you believe you have proven and sketch the method you applied (write the proof out in full if possible).  People here can then comment on the approach (and possibly on the theorem itself).  Otherwise, I think this is just too vague.